# How to destroy... with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

There are models: member(id,project_id,user_id), project(id), user(id), somemodel(id, project_id, user_id).

- member belongs_to :project, belongs_to :user
- somemodel belongs_to :project, belongs_to :user

I would like that when a member is deleted so somemodel (that has project_id and user_id the same as that member) is deleted also. How to do that?

To do that I would like `has_many :somemodels, dependent: :destroy` to be added to member , but I don't know the right parameters to give to `has_many :somemodels` in member class. `has_many :somemodels, dependent: :destroy` alone doesn't work as it tries to search for somemodel by member_id which is not present on the somemodels table and so the `no column` error occurs.

What would be the right `has_many :somemodels ...` to be added to Member?

Comment: @spickermann I would like somemodel instance to be destroyed after member instance is destroyed.

Comment: If `Member` as a model represents a `User` in a specific `Project`, why does `SomeModel` need to have `project_id` and `user_id` too? isn't `Member` supposed to hold that couple of information and then `SomeModel` should be like `somemodel(id, member_id)`?

Comment: @TamerShlash good catch. Your approach would give the solution.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way could be to create a `:through` association for this specific relation, and then set that one to `dependent: :destroy`. I think it would be structured like this:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project

  has_many :some_models, ->(member) { where(user_id: member.user_id) },
                         through: :project,
                         dependent: :destroy
end
```

I haven't tested it, but it seems right as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a after_destroy callback to `Member` model:

```
# In member model
class Member < ApplicationRecord
    after_destroy :also_destroy_somemodel
    ...

   def also_destroy_somemodel
       # Fast, use in case somemodel dont have any callbacks
       Somemodel.where(project_id: project_id, user_id: user_id).delete_all

       # Or
       # Slow, use in case somemodel has callback(s)
       # Somemodel.where(project_id: project_id, user_id: user_id).each &:destroy
   end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good solution, though can I have multiple after_destroy :something, after_destroy: something_else on the same class?

Comment: It's ok. And Rails also has others callback: after_create, after_save, before_save... Check it here: [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)